# Laravel keep chosen select value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an app in Laravel that uses the jQuery [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin.  When a user submits a form I am using requests to validate the form.  However if they are redirected back, for example if they miss a required field, then the Chosen select field does not keep their value.

My code is below.  What am I missing?

**Controller**

```
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.newContractor')
        ->with('timesheetTemplates', $this->timesheet->listTemplates())
        ->with('supervisors', $this->user->getUsersByRole($this->role->findRoleByName('Supervisor')->id)->lists('email', 'id'))
        ->with('contractorRoleId', $this->role->findRoleByName('Contractor')->id)
        ->with('rateFields', $this->rate->all())
        ->with('miscFields', $this->misc->all())
        ->with('workTypes', $this->timesheet->getTypeWork());
}
```

**View**

```
{!! Form::open([]) !!}
...

    {!! Form::label('supervisors', 'Assign Supervisor(s)') !!}
    {!! Form::select('supervisors[][supervisor_id]', $supervisors, null, ['class' => 'chosen-select', 'multiple']) !!}

... 
{!! Form::close([]) !!}
```

**Request**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as ValidatorFactory;
use String;

class CreateUserRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name'        => 'required',
            'last_name'         => 'required',
            'email'             => 'required|unique:user,email',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function validator(ValidatorFactory $factory)
    {
        if(!$this->get('status'))
        {
            $this->merge(['activation_code' => String::random(30)]);
        }

        return $factory->make($this->input(), $this->rules(), $this->messages());
    }
}
```

**Edit:** The result of `$this->rate->all()` is:

```
Collection {#315 ▼
#items: array:4 [▼
  0 => Rate {#316 ▼
    #table: "rate"
    #fillable: array:3 [▶]
    +timestamps: true
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    #attributes: array:6 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "cust_id" => 1
      "field" => "hourly_rate"
      "name" => "Hourly Rate"
      "created_at" => "2015-09-07 08:11:46"
      "updated_at" => "2015-09-07 08:11:46"
    ]
    #original: array:6 [▶]
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  }
  1 => Rate {#317 ▶}
  2 => Rate {#318 ▶}
  3 => Rate {#319 ▶}
]
```

}

Comment: What is the output of `$this->rate->all()` in your controller method? You are generating text fields. Are you sure that they being generated correctly? Also, are they properly saved in your database upon correctly submitting the form?

Comment: The result of `$this->rate->all()` is a Collection which I have copied above.  I am pretty sure the fields are being generated properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Form::select()`, the third parameter is the default value.

```
Form::select($field_name, $options, $selected);
```

You're currently passing in `null`. You need to pass in the value or values which you'd like to be selected upon load. As you're using a multi select, you'll need to pass an array of ids.

The best way to repopulate the field is then to use the `old()` helper function, or the longer form `Input::old()`. For example

```
Form::select('myfield[]', $options, old('myfield', $default_if_no_old));
```

That said, the way that you've structured your form will mean that you can't use these methods because they only support a single dimension to the field name.

```
Form::select('supervisors[][supervisor_id]' ...
```

The second dimension, supervisor_id causes the resulting form data to look as follows

```
[supervisors] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [supervisor_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [supervisor_id] => 3
        )
)
```

When it rebuilds the form, it causes it to check if the `key == [supervisor_id] => 2]` which it obviously doesn't, so it doesn't reselect it.

Ideally structure your form and just collect `supervisor_ids[]` rather than `supervisors[]` and build the `supervisors` array behind the scenes.

If you can't do that, then you'll need to build a custom method, perhaps as a Form::macro which manages this for you.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong fields by mistake.  I have update my question now with the correct fields which are not keeping the value and they are using the `select()` method within blade.